# What does options.hashTypes do in Handlebars helpers?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In the `input` and `textarea` handlebar helpers in Ember there is a function `normalizeHash`:

```
function normalizeHash(hash, hashTypes) {
  for (var prop in hash) {
    if (hashTypes[prop] === 'ID') {
      hash[prop + 'Binding'] = hash[prop];
      delete hash[prop];
    }
  }
}
```

the `hashTypes` are passed in from `options.hashTypes`:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('input', function(options) {
  Ember.assert('You can only pass attributes to the `input` helper, not arguments', arguments.length < 2);

  var hash = options.hash,
      types = options.hashTypes,
      inputType = hash.type,
      onEvent = hash.on;

  delete hash.type;
  delete hash.on;

  normalizeHash(hash, types);

  if (inputType === 'checkbox') {
    return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, Ember.Checkbox, options);
  } else {
    hash.type = inputType;
    hash.onEvent = onEvent || 'enter';
    return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, Ember.TextField, options);
  }
});
```

I've been trying to understand what `normalizeHash` is doing but I can't find any documentation on `options.hashTypes`. So, my question is what is `options.hashTypes`?

Thanks!